# Excel VBA fill in last empty row with value between A16-A20

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to make a code where when I press a button, the system automatically fill in cells with value. What I want is when row 16 is filled with value, the system detects it and fill in the row below ( not overwrite the value of row 16) for example if row 16 is filled then row 17 is filled.

I already try making the code but the problem is it only overwrite row 16, it doesn't fill in the next row when row 16 is already filled with a value

this is the code:

```
Dim lr As Long
Dim TxtRng As Range

lr = Sheets("5barang").Range("A16:A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
Sheets("5barang").Range("A" & lr).Value = "CHEETOS"
Sheets("5barang").Range("C" & lr).Value = "1"
Sheets("5barang").Range("D" & lr).Value = "60000"

End Sub
```

[image: excel table]

Answer (score 1):

The below code should work for you:

```
Dim lr As Long, count_entries As Integer
Dim TxtRng As String

TxtRng = "A16:A20"
count_entries = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(range(TxtRng), "<>")

If count_entries = 1 Then
    lr = Sheets("5barang").range("A17").Row
Else
    lr = Sheets("5barang").range(TxtRng).End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Row
End If

Sheets("5barang").range("A" & lr).Value = "CHEETOS"
Sheets("5barang").range("C" & lr).Value = "1"
Sheets("5barang").range("D" & lr).Value = "60000"
```

I've edited the code to only include range A16:A20. But note that this **may not work properly after A20**.

And as per your comment, you have protected the sheet. So you'll have to unprotect the sheet before running the code. Or you can add a code to [Unprotect the sheet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.unprotect) with the above code.

Comment: I try and it said that im trying to enter value to a protected sheet. does your lr detect that I want to input only between row A16 until A20 ?

Comment: now your code works, but when I empty all the cells again the count doesn't reset so when I try to input again it doesn't start from row16 again (example: when field A17 is filled then it fill in A18 but when I erase A17 and try again, it fills in A19)

Comment: This code currently works in the order of Rows. I.e., if you want to fill in A17, A18:A20 should be empty.

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
Dim items As Long, rw As Long
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("5barang")
    .Unprotect
    items = .Range("A15:A20").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count
    If items < 6 Then
        rw = .Cells(15, 1).End(xlDown).Row + 1
        .Range("A" & rw).Value = "CHEETOS"
        .Range("C" & rw).Value = 1
        .Range("D" & rw).Value = 60000
    Else
        MsgBox "Matrix is full already"
    End If
    .Protect
End With
```